# If polynomial $ax^4 +bx^2 +c$ has four real roots?

Tags: polynomials, roots

A polynomial $ax^4 + bx^2 + c$ where $a,b,c$ are positive while $x$ is a
real variable, does it have four real roots or 2 real roots? Is there any formula or way to find how many real roots this polynomial has?

Comment: It obviously depends on the number of non-negative roots of the polynomial $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

Comment: For instance $4x^4+x^2+5$ has no real root.

Comment: Before asking such a question, you should have made some attempts with a graphic tool: you would have seen that you **never** have a single real root, as said by @Fred Akalin !

Comment: If $a,b,c$ need not be positive, you could try making the substitution $y=x^2$ and using the quadratic formula to solve for $y$. Be careful, as you will need to then verify which solutions $x=\pm\sqrt y$ work for the original equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a, b, and c are positive, and x is real, then the whole expression is positive, and thus it has no real roots.

Comment: is there any proof for that?
suppose this equation x^2+5x+6 this equation has (x+2) (x+3) we cant generalize that for every case 
but for x^4+5x^2+6 it has no real roots that is true

Comment: @ganesh your equation has a term of $x$, which is an odd power of $x$. The equation Fred Akalin is responding to has only even powers of $x$, which are always nonnegative.

Comment: got it thanks.....

Comment: Yeap, sorry should have been more clear. The fact that your polynomial only has even degrees was the key.

Comment: @ganesh $ax^2 + bx + c$ will factor as $(x + r_1)(x+r_2)$, where both $r_1$ and $r_2$ are positive, if it factors at all, meaning the solutions are $x = -r_1$ and $x = -r_2$. If you look at $ax^4 + bx^2 + c$, making the substitution $u = x^2$, then you're looking for roots of $au^2 + bu + c$. By the above, if there are solutions for $u$, they're negative. But then you're solving $u = x^2 = [\text{something negative}]$ which will have no real solutions for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the values of a,b, and c.  Although if they are all positive there are no real real root.

The quadratic formula says that:

$x^2 =\frac {-b\pm\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a} $

Consider the following cases:

1: $b^2 < 4ac $.

Then it is impossible for $x^2$ to have any value.  So no solution.

2: $b^2=4ac $ then $x^2=\frac {-b}{2a} $

2a: $a $ and $b $ are same sign.

Then $x^2 <0$ which is impossible so no solutions.

2b: $b=0$.  Then $x=0$

2c: $a,b $ are opposite signs. Then there are two solutions: $\pm\sqrt {\frac {-b}{2a}} $.

3: $b^2>4ac$

3a: $b>0;a>0;c>0$ then $|b|>\sqrt {b^2-4ac} $ so both the solutions for $x^2$ are negative.  So no solutions.

[So for this problem either case 1, 2a, or 3a apply so no solutions.]

3b: $b>0$ and $c=0$ $a>0$

Then $x^2=0$ or $x^2=\frac {-b}{a}<0 $.  So $x=0$.

3c: $b>0$ and $c=0$ $a <0$

Then there are three solutions: $0,\pm\sqrt {\frac {-b}{a}} $.

3d: $b>0$ $a <0;c <0$

There are 4 solutions: $\pm \sqrt {\frac {-b\pm\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}} $

Okay, getting sick of typing.... the remaining cases are done similarly